# How to show setTimeout image before showing content in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have button that has a on.click(function() {}. Inside the click function is a setTimeout( function() {} that will show the content from external html file.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary choose-iphone-btn">Jet Black</button>

    $(function() {

        $('.choose-iphone-btn').click(function() {

            setTimeout( function() {

                $.get('iphone-checkout.html')
                 .success(function(data) {
                     $('.iphone-pre-order-sales-content-info').html(data);
                });

            }, 3000);

        });

});
```

I want to display

```
<img src="images/default.gif" />
```

for 3 seconds before showing iphone-checkout.html.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add a call to `$("img").show()` before the `setTimeout()`, and a call to `.hide()` in the Ajax success handler?

Comment: can you write the code for me please?

Comment: @redshot first try yourself, thats the best way to learn. Do the research, you know the functions you need. Look at jQuery api and docs, they have detailed info explaining those functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a class to your `img`, say `loading`

```
<img class="loading" src="images/default.gif" />
```

Show and hide the same within click event.

```
$('.choose-iphone-btn').click(function() {
     $(".loading").show(); //get reference to element with its class and show it
     setTimeout( function() {
         $.get('iphone-checkout.html')
           .success(function(data) {
              $(".loading").hide();//hide once your ajax is success
              $('.iphone-pre-order-sales-content-info').html(data);
        });
     }, 3000);
});
```

You can also `hide` the `loading` in `.done` event, so that even in `ajax` failure, it doesn't block your view or keep displaying it.

```
$('.choose-iphone-btn').click(function() {
     $(".loading").show(); //get reference to element with its class and show it
     setTimeout( function() {
         $.get('iphone-checkout.html')
           .success(function(data) {
              $('.iphone-pre-order-sales-content-info').html(data);
           });
           .done(function() {
              $(".loading").hide();//hide once your ajax request is done
           });
      }, 3000);
 });
```

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Create a class to display/hide the image. Initially set it to `display:none`.

Then use jquery `addClass` & `removeClass` method to show and hide the image

CSS

```
.displayNone{
  display:none
}
```

HTML

```
// added id & class to image tag
<img id="myImage" class="displayNone" src="images/default.gif" />
```

JS

```
$('.choose-iphone-btn').click(function() {
        // removing the class to display the image
        $("#myImage").removeClass("displayNone");
        setTimeout( function() {

            $.get('iphone-checkout.html')
             .success(function(data) {
                 $('.iphone-pre-order-sales-content-info').html(data);
                 // adding class back on to hide mage on success of ajax
                 $("#myImage").addClass("displayNone");
            });

        }, 3000);

    });
```